# print multiple variables in a string what is the correct syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just getting started with python. I have experience with some other languages I was just curious what the correct syntax would be to print the output of multiple variables in a string. or even the same variable multiple times in a string.

```
arg1 = 1

arg2 = 2

print ("arg1 =",arg1) # <---------------------------this works 

arg1 = 1

print ("arg1 =",arg1 "arg2",arg2) # <----------------why not this ?
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're missing a comma. `arg1 "arg2"` isn't a valid expression.

Comment: I meant to put "arg2 =",arg2    so i was expecting to see the print output say arg1 =1 agr2=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument would be `arg1 "arg2"` which is not a valid expression. If you want to print both `arg1` and `"arg2"`, you should separate it by another comma:

```
print("arg1 =", arg1, "arg2 =", arg2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One thing i should have mentioned is I also want these two variables to show up in the same string. not sure the best way to do this.  Basically what i want to do is print multiple variables in one print statement. I understand how to do this when I want to print a single variable but how to do this when in the print statement i want to print the output of two or more variables.

Comment: @Matt If you try that print call from my answer, you will see that the text is automatically combined, so for `arg = 1` and `arg2 = 2`, the output would be `arg 1 = 1 arg2 = 2`—in a single line.

Comment: Ok I see I think I just needed to add the comma before and after the variable in arg1. I tried your output and your correct. Thanks so much I appreciate your help.

Comment: print("arg1 =", arg1, "arg2 =", arg2) #;this is what i wanted thanks
arg1 = 1 arg2 = 2

Answer (score 2):

As @Wooble points out, you have a syntax error. But let's clarify how this works in Python.

```
print(a, b, c, d,....)
```

is basically the same as

```
output = " ".join(a, b, c, d)
print(output)
```

If you want to output the same variable multiple times, sometimes `format` is better. http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: I understand how achieve this when there is no text in the print statement. but how to achieve this when you want to combine literal text and print the output of a variable in the same print statement.

Comment: @Matt he told you how to do that.

Comment: There is no difference from a literal string and a variable containing a string. You just add what you want output and use commas to separate them. Personally, I prefer and use `format` for anything one than simple `print(a)` or `print("this is a:", a)`.